# How to add a UserProfile to a User when user signs up? (Devise, Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I want to override Devise's `RegistrationsContollers`' create action so that when a user signs up, I can associate a `UserProfile` model with that user.

So, following the guidelines in the Devise Readme, I override the action:

```
#File app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:    
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    # some code here..
    self.user_profiles.build #Error (no method `user_profiles`)
    current_user.user_profiles.build #Error (current_user is nil)
    some other way???
  end
end

#File routes.rb:
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'users/registrations' }
```

Devise is creating a record in the `users` table, but how do I associate a `UserProfile` with that record?

I've tried googling but I simply can't get this to work! Any help is much appreciated.

(I'm now using Devise 1.1.5 on Rails 3.0.3)

**SOLVED:**

Adding solution for benefit of others:

```
#File app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:    
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super
    @user.build_user_profile
    @user.user_profile.some_data = 'abcd'
    @user.save!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` refers to the contoller not the model in this context.

Also, does the user model have many UserProfiles? Otherwise if they don't (ie they only have one), then you should use `@user.build_user_profile`, not `@user.user_profiles.build`

I'd also recommend doing this at the model level, not the controller level, using a callback such as `before_create` or `after_create`, ie:

```
class User < AR
    has_one :user_profile

    after_create :build_profile 

    def build_profile
        self.build_user_profile
        ...
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! that works (@user.build_user_profile). Also, I need to create the profile in the controller (not in the model) because some input from the user is needed at sign up time (such as address).

Comment: If you're passing in data from another model, in this case the UserProfile, you could look at using `:accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the User model and `fields_for` in the signup form, this way you'd be able to do everything you need at the model level, in fact, it would allow you to create the associated model implicitly without having to write a line of code.